# возвести в степень без функций, может кто знает?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

main()
{
    long i, x, y, z;

    for (long i = 0, x = 0; x >= 0 ; i++)

    {
        printf("%d\n", x = i * i * i * i * i);
    }

    for (long y = 0, z = 0; z <= 0; y--)
    {
        printf("%d\n", z = y * y * y * y * y);
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Найти все значение всех чисел в 5 степени не выходящих за пределы long, у меня переполнение получается, помогите сделать без переполнения, на языке си.  Обратите внимание, что они могут быть как положительными так и отрицательными.

запрещено использовать вещественные типы переменных и библиотекой .

Выходной поток должен содержать найденные значения по одному на строке. Значения не должны повторяться. Порядок не важен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте беззнаковый тип

Comment: Мне нужно отрицательные тоже вывести

Comment: Переполнение...

Comment: Возьмите целую часть от корня 5 степени от `LONG_MAX` и вычислите все степени от этого числа до 0. Корень можно искать, например, по алгоритму из [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8].

Comment: Возвести все числа в 5 степень < LONG_MAX    например: 0, 1, 32, 64, 128, 256.......<LONG_MAX

Comment: Ребят не знаете как сделать ? Без flag to stop я не знаю что это значит, по простому помогите сделать

Comment: @King.c используй строку. там ты можешь возвести в степень хоть миллиард в 10 степени

Answer (score 1):

При каждом умножении нужно сохранять предыдущее значение. И контролировать делением.

```
for ( i = 1 ; флаг не стоп ; ++ i ) {
  x = 1 ;
  for ( степень = 5 ; степень > 0 ; ) {
    -- степень ;
    xold = x ;
    x = x * i ;
    if ( (x / i) == xold ) то пока всё в порядке
    else переполнение случилось, останавливаемся } }
```

Вот цикл подробнее :

```
bool flag_to_stop = false ;
for ( long int i = 1 ; not flag_to_stop ; ++ i ) {
  long int x = 1 ;
  for ( int power = 5 ; power > 0 ; ) {
    -- power ;
    long int xold = x ;
    x = x * i ;
    if ( (  x / i ) != xold ) {
      flag_to_stop = true ;
      break ; } } }
```

Comment: Alex, можно по подробнее что значит флаг не стоп?  И что должно стоять в условии else что должно стоять,  если не трудно объясниту

Comment: посмотрите более подробный пример в ответе

Comment: переполнение знакового числа это UB. Вы НЕ МОЖЕТЕ рассчитывать на любое ожидаемое поведение программы при нем

Answer (score 0):

Ещё такой вариант, без возможности переполнения:

```
int main()
{
    long base = -73;
    long exp = 5;
    long powr = 1;
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
        if (base > 0)
            flag = flag && (powr < LONG_MAX / base);
        else {
            if (powr > 0)
                flag = flag && (powr < LONG_MIN / base);
            else
                flag = flag && (powr > LONG_MAX / base);
        }
        if (flag)
            powr *= base;
        else
            break;
    }
    if (flag)
       std::cout << base << " OK\n";
    else
        std::cout << base << " Too large :( \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает кармы для комментирования, извините, напишу сюда. Я не совсем понял задание, что должно помещаться в long? Возводимая в пятую степень переменная или результат возведения? Если результат возведения, то всё просто: 6208^5 ещё не переполняет long, 6209^5 уже переполняет. Можно в принципе использовать unsigned long, в конце концов возведение в пятую степень отрицательного числа равно пятой степени этого же положительного числа со знаком минус. Код с unsigned long:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

long i = 0;
unsigned long j;

while(i < 7132){
    j = i * i * i * i * i;
    printf("%ld\t->\t%lu\n", i, j);
    printf("-%ld\t->\t-%lu\n", i, j); // вычислять отрицательные значения пятой степени бессмысленно - просто допишем минус
    i++;}
return 0;}
```

7132^5 уже переполняет unsigned long